# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

- List item

I get this exception when I add my second controller.
I do have one controller already and that webpage is working well
But now I added a second controller and  I get his error WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/civilforsvaret-webbapp2/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
THe thing  I dont understand is why one page is displaying but not the other?

Here is the DispatcherServlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>civilforsvaret-webbapp2</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here is my serlvet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="se.lowdin.civilforsvaret" />  

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
  </bean>
```

And this is my structure :

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUnyc.jpg)

My contorller :

```
Controller
@RequestMapping("/login.html")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this error it means that your uri does not match.
So you either have a wrong url in your .jsp page or in your controller.

So to get rid of this make sure that your `@RequestMapping() or in your return statement` is matching the url you call in your .jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set common part of path for controller and then use specific path for every method inside your controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method(Map model) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="login.html")
    public String method2(Map model) {
        ...
    }

}
```