# DispatcherServlet not able to find mapping URI for the HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic

I know there are similiar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910482/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri), but I have done the corrections mentioned on that page yet I get this error whenever I get a redirection to my landing controller.

```
2021-05-10 09:30:54 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:693 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing POST request for [/myPortal/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet]
2021-05-10 09:30:54 WARN  PageNotFound:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myPortal/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher
```

Below are my configurations, can anyone please point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.microsoft.aad.adal4jsample" />
    
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>/myPortal</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

And my landing controller:

```
package com.microsoft.aad.adal4jsample;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/jsp/MyClientControllerServlet")
public class AadController {

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String getDirectoryObjects(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding below piece of block in my dispatch-servlet.xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />
</bean>
```